# For the expectation of a random variable $Y$, what does the $dy$ term imply in: $\mathbb{E}[Y] = \int_{\mathcal{Y}}y \ p(dy)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

For a random variable $Y$, assume that it has distribution $p$ on a space $\mathcal{Y}$. Then, I have seen the expectation of $Y$ written as:

$$
\mathbb{E}[Y] = \int_{\mathcal{Y}}y \ p(dy)
$$

I am wondering why there is a $dy$ inside of the distribution $p$. Is this perhaps referencing the Lebesgue measure?

Comment: This is the Lebesgue integral.  You're integrating the function $f(y) = y$ over the space $\mathcal{Y}$ with respect to the measure $p$.  The $dy$ is there to let you know the variable of integration, and is useful in multivariable situations.  For example, if $f$ were actually $f(x,y)$, depending on $x$ and $y$, you may decide to integrate with respect to a single variable, say, $y$, so that the role of $dy$ in $\int \limits_{\mathcal{Y}} f(x,y) \,p(dy)$ is more clear.

Comment: The Lebesgue integral in the general sense, but not necessarily with Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @user46944 What is the "$d$" in front of the $y$ signify? Or is it just notational convention?

Comment: This is the general convention that $$\int_X u(x)\mu(dx)$$ is the integral of the function $u:X\to\mathbb R$ with respect to the measure $\mu$ defined on (some sigma-algebra on) $X$.

Comment: @Did I have seen people write the relation $\mu(dx) = \mu(x)dx$. Do you know why this is true?

Comment: It is not since it confuses a measure $\mu$ with its (possibly nonexistent) density with respect to the Lebesgue measure.